# MaskedEditExtender in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Masked edit extender in my gridview. I am displaying this gridview dynamically based on types, If the type is 'T' it displayes only textbox, if the type is 'DT' it displays textbox with calendar.

I am using the same textbox, and in grid row databound event, I am hiding and showing the calendar button.  But if I give the maskededitextender in the gridview, the mask is being applied for the nondate fields also.

I tried by giving a dummy textbox and make it as targetcontrolid for the maskededtextender and in rowdatabound event, I am setting the targetcontrolid of the maskededitextender to my textbox if the type is date. But it is not working.

can anyone please help me on this?

Below is the rowdatabound event code:

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                     MaskedEditExtender ME = (MaskedEditExtender)e.Row.FindControl("MaskedEditExtender1");  
                     TextBox txtValue1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtValue1");  
                     TextBox txttest = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txttest");  
                     HiddenField hfInputType = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfInputType");  
                     ImageButton imgBtnFromDate = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnFromDate");  
                     ME.TargetControlID = txttest.ClientID;  
                     if(hfInputType.Value=="DT")  
                     {  
                        txtValue1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");  
                        imgBtnFromDate.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");  
                        ME.TargetControlID = txtValue1.ClientID;  
                     }  
                    else if(hfInputType.Value=="U")  
                     {  
                        txtValue1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");  
                        imgBtnFromDate.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");  
                     }  
                }  
            }  
        }
```

Asp.net code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnFromDate" runat="server" Style="display: none" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Black/Images/Calendar.png" />  
                                                        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="ceFromDate" PopupButtonID="imgBtnFromDate" runat="server"
                                                            TargetControlID="txtValue1">  
                                                        </cc1:CalendarExtender>  
                                                        <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" AcceptNegative="Left"
                                                        DisplayMoney="Left" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" TargetControlID="txttest"
                                                        AutoComplete="true" SkinID="TextBoxWatermarkExtenderSkin" UserDateFormat="MonthDayYear">
                                                       </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

Comment: Can you share few of your code where you set up target control id and etc?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your quick response, i have added my code above.